# Difference between ofVec2f and ofPoint

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I'm learning Openframeworks and have found that these two classes are often used to represent sometimes vectors and sometimes points. What are the reasons for using one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ofPoint` is in fact just an `ofVec3f`. It is defined like this:

```
typedef ofVec3f ofPoint;
```

(See [here](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/types/ofPoint.h) for the code)

I think it's just a question of convenience. When you want to represent a point in a 3-dimensional space, it's more explicit to use an `ofPoint` than an `ofVec3f` and it makes your code more readable.

Comment: I'd suggest it's more explicit to use ofVec3f than ofPoint.  ofPoint hides the 2D vs. 3D features.  Additionally, if you don't need the 3rd dimension, using ofVec2f will be (very slightly) faster because the vector math won't include the 3rd dimension.